# Erro java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java, FX, Hibernate e usando o log4j2 para meus logs. Quando eu executo a aplicação pela IDE (Eclipse) tudo funciona normalmente, mas ao criar o .jar da aplicação, aparece os seguintes erros (justamente na hora de iniciar o banco de dados no Hibernate) :

```
26/01/2016 11:22:32.186 [ INFO] LogHelper.java:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: crp
    ...]
26/01/2016 11:22:32.243 [ INFO] Version.java:37 - HHH000412: Hibernate  Core {5.0.7.Final}
26/01/2016 11:22:32.248 [ INFO] Environment.java:198 - HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
26/01/2016 11:22:32.250 [ INFO] Environment.java:317 - HHH000021:Bytecode provider name : javassist
26/01/2016 11:22:32.293 [ INFO] JavaReflectionManager.java:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
26/01/2016 11:22:33.761 [ERROR] Conexao.java:20 - Erro em Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(crp) => Unable to build entity manager factory javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.org.eldorado.crp.util.Conexao.<clinit>(Conexao.java:18)
    at br.org.eldorado.crp.controller.Tasks$2.call(Tasks.java:39)
    at br.org.eldorado.crp.controller.Tasks$2.call(Tasks.java:1)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.
db.jpa.converter.ContextMapJsonAttributeConverter] 
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
26/01/2016 11:22:33.863 [ERROR] MainController.java:433 - Falha ao conectar com o banco de dados!
```

Estou totalmente perdido em onde possa estar o erro. Por favor, alguém consegue dar alguma ajuda, pelo menos para entender o que está acontecendo.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: É possível confirmar se todas dependências foram adicionadas junto ao .jar?

Comment: Java é novidade pra mim, então vou ter dificuldade em algumas coisas. Renomeando o .jar e abrindo com um zip vejo o hibernate, o FX e meu software lá dentro (todos os models e todos os controllers). O que eu fiquei em dúvida é quanto ao log4j2. Tem um log4j dentro da pasta Apache e um slf4j. Creio que isso seja do log4j2. Como ver as dependências de forma mais detalhada? Obrigado @douglas-galdino

Comment: O SLF4J é um facade para logs no Java, é como uma interface, uma abstração para diversas bibliotecas de log, mas para essa interface funcionar, precisa da implementação  escolhida pelo desenvolvedor, algumas existentes são Log4J2, Logback, Simple Log, etc. Então além da dependência do SLF4J, no seu caso é necessário da do Log4J 1.2 ou 2, uma das duas, dependendo de qual versão/binding do slf4j você escolheu. Para olhar mais detalhadamente, sem estar utilizando nenhum gerenciador de dependências, é olhar por pastas mesmo.

Comment: @DouglasGaldino, por favor me corrija se eu estiver enganado. Um dos erros gerados é `ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`. Realmente esse fasterxml não existe no meu .jar. Eu teria que adicioná-lo ao meu projeto? Eu não uso ele diretamente. Quem será que usa ele? Obrigado.

Comment: Parece ser uma depedência do Jackson, que é uma biblioteca de processamento de formatos de dados como XML e JSON.
É sempre legal utilizar gerenciadores de dependências como Maven/Gradle poís em um caso como esse, é geralmente resolvido automaticamente pelo gerenciador, ele faz o download de todas dependências pertinentes a aquela biblioteca na qual você esta utilizando. Mas para resolver no seu caso tente adicionar essa biblioteca. 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Comment: Adicionando os jars `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations.jar` e `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar` o problema foi resolvido. Muito obrigado @DouglasGaldino

Comment: Como resolveu com outras dependências, você pode colocar uma resposta com a solução e aceitar a mesma como resposta. Não foi nada :]

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se as dependências do Jackson foram incluídas no seu *jar*.

Você pode fazer isso abrindo o `.jar` do seu projeto e verificando se existe o `.jar` do Jackson lá dentro, caso não tenha, adicione e empacote novamente.

Caso esteja usando um gerenciador de dependência como Maven ou Gradle, é só adicionar a depêndencia nos arquivos de configuração, `pom.xml` para maven e `build.gradle` para gradle.